# Integral and inequality

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $p(u,x):=(4 \pi u)^{-1/2}e^{-\frac{x^2}{4u}},u>0,x \in \mathbb{R}.$

Let $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}),\text{supp}(\phi) \subset B(0,1),||\phi||_{\infty} \leq 1.$

Prove that for all $U>0,\beta>1/2,$ there exist $\epsilon>0,C>0$ such that for all $u\in [0,U],\lambda \in \left]0,1\right],$ $$\int_0^{u} \int_{\mathbb{R}} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi^\lambda(y_1)p(r,y_1-y_2) dy_1 \right)^2 dy_2 dr\leq Cu^\varepsilon \lambda^{1-2\beta},$$
where $\phi^\lambda(y) = \lambda^{-1} \phi(\lambda^{-1}y).$

I tried, using a change of variable, replacing $\phi^{\lambda}$ with $\phi.$ also $\lambda(B(0,1))<\infty$ might be useful.

How can we prove this inequality?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define
$$\begin{aligned}
I_1&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty I_2^2\text{ d}y_2\\
I_2&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac1\lambda\phi\left(\frac{y_1}{\lambda}\right)\cdot\frac1{\sqrt{4\pi r}}e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/4r}\text{ d}y_1\\
\end{aligned}$$
then the result we want to show is that
$$I=\int_0^{u}I_1\text{ d}r\leq Cu^\epsilon\lambda^{1/2-\beta}$$
First, we'll simplify $I_2$. Since $\phi(x)$ is nonzero only for $-1\leq x\leq 1$, $\phi(\frac{y_1}{\lambda})$ is nonzero only for $-1\leq \frac{y_1}{\lambda}\leq 1$, or $-\lambda\leq y_1\leq\lambda$. Therefore,
$$I_2=\frac1{\lambda\sqrt{4\pi r}}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\phi\left(\frac{y_1}{\lambda}\right)e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/4r}\text{ d}y_1$$
Next, expand out $I_1$, and do the $y_2$ integral first: (the validity of interchanging the integrals follows from $|\phi(x)|\leq1$)
$$\begin{aligned}
I_1&=\frac1{4\pi r\lambda^2}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left(\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\phi\left(\frac{y_1}{\lambda}\right)e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/4r}\text{ d}y_1\right)\left(\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\phi\left(\frac{y_1'}{\lambda}\right)e^{-(y_1'-y_2)^2/4r}\text{ d}y_1'\right)\text{ d}y_2\\
&=\frac1{4\pi r\lambda^2}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\phi\left(\frac{y_1}{\lambda}\right)\phi\left(\frac{y_1'}{\lambda}\right)\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{(y_2-y_1)^2+(y_2-y_1')^2}{4r}\right)\text{ d}y_2\text{ d}y_1\text{ d}y_1'
\end{aligned}$$
The innermost integral may be evaluated as
$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac{(y_2-y_1)^2+(y_2-y_1')^2}{4r}\right)\text{ d}y_2&=e^{-(y_1-y_1')^2/8r}\int_{-\infty}^\infty\exp\left(-\frac1{2r}\left(y_2-\frac{y_1+y_1'}2\right)^2\right)\text{ d}y_2\\
&=e^{-(y_1-y_1')^2/8r}\sqrt{2\pi r}
\end{aligned}$$
Substituting this back into $I_1$ gives
$$\begin{aligned}
I_1&=\frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi r}\lambda^2}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\phi\left(\frac{y_1}{\lambda}\right)\phi\left(\frac{y_1'}{\lambda}\right)e^{-(y_1-y_1')^2/8r}\text{ d}y_1\text{ d}y_1'\\
&\leq\frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi r}\lambda^2}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}e^{-(y_1-y_1')^2/8r}\text{ d}y_1\text{ d}y_1'\\
&\leq\frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi r}\lambda^2}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\text{ d}y_1\text{ d}y_1'\\
&=\frac{4\lambda^2}{2\sqrt{2\pi r}\lambda^2}\\
&=\sqrt{\frac2\pi}r^{-1/2}
\end{aligned}$$
where we have used the bounds $|\phi|\leq1$ and $e^{-x^2}\le1$. Note that equality holds only when $\lambda=0$. Integrating $I_1$, we arrive at
$$\begin{aligned}
I&=\int_0^{u}I_1\text{ d}r\\
&\le\sqrt{\frac2\pi}\int_0^{u}r^{-1/2}\text{ d}r\\&=2\sqrt{\frac2\pi}u^{1/2}
\end{aligned}$$
This shows that as long as you pick $C\ge2\sqrt{2/\pi},\epsilon\ge1/2$, we will always have
$$I\le2\sqrt{\frac2\pi}u^{1/2}\le Cu^{1/2}\le Cu^{1/2}\lambda^{1-2\beta}$$
since $\lambda^{1-2\beta}\ge1$ for all $0\le\lambda\le1,\beta>1/2$.
By the way, if you still need a tighter bound, you can actually compute the double integral in the first inequality for $I_1$ explicitly in terms of error functions:
$$\begin{aligned}
I_1&=\frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi r}\lambda^2}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\phi\left(\frac{y_1}{\lambda}\right)\phi\left(\frac{y_1'}{\lambda}\right)e^{-(y_1-y_1')^2/8r}\text{ d}y_1\text{ d}y_1'\\
&\leq\frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi r}\lambda^2}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}\int_{-\lambda}^{\lambda}e^{-(y_1-y_1')^2/8r}\text{ d}y_1\text{ d}y_1'\\
&=\frac1{2\sqrt{2\pi r}\lambda^2}\left(4\sqrt{2\pi r}\lambda\text{ erf}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2r}}\right)+8r\left(e^{-\lambda^2/2r}-1\right)\right)\\
&=\frac2\lambda\text{ erf}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2r}}\right)+\frac{2}{\lambda^2}\sqrt{\frac{2r}{\pi}}\left(e^{-\lambda^2/2r}-1\right)
\end{aligned}$$
Integrating with respect to $r$, we obtain
$$\begin{aligned}
I&=\int_0^{u}I_1\text{ d}r\\
&\le\int_0^{u}\frac2\lambda\text{ erf}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2r}}\right)+\frac{2}{\lambda^2}\sqrt{\frac{2r}{\pi}}\left(e^{-\lambda^2/2r}-1\right)\text{ d}r\\
&=\frac{2u}\lambda\text{ erf}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2u}}\right)-\frac23\lambda
\left(1-\text{ erf}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2u}}\right)\right)+\frac{4}{3}\sqrt{\frac{2}\pi}\frac{u^{3/2}}{\lambda^{2}}\left(e^{-\lambda^2/2u}-1\right)+\frac23\sqrt{\frac{2u}\pi}e^{-\lambda^2/2u}
\end{aligned}$$
This is actually the tightest possible bound for $I$ in terms of just $u,\lambda$ since you can construct bump functions that become arbitrarily close to $1$ over $(-1,1)$. Therefore, you can always find $\phi$ such that $I$ becomes arbitrarily close to this bound. Also, you can verify that this expression equals $2\sqrt{2/\pi}u^{1/2}$ when $\lambda=0$.

Comment: It's possible to generalize this to $\mathbb{R}^2,$ by considering $p(u,x):=(4 \pi u)^{-1}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{4u}},u>0,x,y \in \mathbb{R},$ and we should obtain $\lambda^{-2\beta}$ on the RHS. Do you have ideas how to prove it? the problem is that $\int_0^u1/rdr$ is not integrable.

Comment: Can you give more details about your generalisation? There are many ways to generalise to $\mathbb R^2$. For example, would $\phi(x)$ be generalised as $\phi(x,y)$ or $\phi(x)\phi(y)$? It would be better if you could post the precise question as an edit or as a new question.

Comment: We are considering in $\mathbb{R}^2,p(u,x,y):=(4 \pi u)^{-1}e^{-\frac{x^2+y^2}{4u}},u>0,x ,y\in \mathbb{R}.$ $\phi \in C_c^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2),\text{supp}(\phi) \subset B(0,1),||\phi||_{\infty} \leq 1.$ In this case we have $\int_0^{u} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \phi^\lambda(y_1)p(r,y_1-y_2) dy_1 \right)^2 dy_2 dr\leq Cu^\varepsilon \lambda^{-2\beta},$ how can we prove this generalization? The problem is that $\int^u_01/rdr$ is not integrable
 is not integrable.

Comment: Where $\phi^{\lambda}(x)=\lambda^{-2}\phi(x/\lambda),x\in\mathbb{R}^2.$

Comment: This would be solved if we could prove $\forall u\in [0,U],\lambda\in]0,1],\int_0^u\int_{[-1,1]^2}\int_{[-1,1]^2}\frac{1}{r}e^{-\lambda^2|x-y|^2/r}dxdydr\leq Cu^{\epsilon}\lambda^{-2\beta},
|.|$ the euclidean norm

Comment: B(0,1) under the euclidean norm in $\mathbb R^2$ should be the unit disc instead of $[-1,1]^2$, right? So the region of integration can be made even smaller than the one you supplied, although I'm not sure if that makes finding a bound easier.

Comment: With $[-1,1]^2$ as the domain of integration, the integral to be bounded can be expressed as $\int_0^u\left(\frac2\lambda\text{ erf}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2r}}\right)+\frac{2}{\lambda^2}\sqrt{\frac{2r}{\pi}}\left(e^{-\lambda^2/2r}-1\right)\right)^2\text{ d}r$ ,and while this can't be integrated in terms of elementary functions and $\text{erf}$, you can try getting a bound out of it. Numerically, it definitely seems to be finite for $\lambda\neq0$

Comment: The expression inside the square can also be written as a (possibly easier to work with) series $\frac2\lambda\text{ erf}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2r}}\right)+\frac{2}{\lambda^2}\sqrt{\frac{2r}{\pi}}\left(e^{-\lambda^2/2r}-1\right)=\sqrt{\frac2{\pi r}}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)(n+1)!}\left(\frac{\lambda^2}{2r}\right)^n$, which allows the integral to be computed as a series at least, although the coefficients will be fairly ugly sums

Answer (score 0):

Let $U>0$ and $\beta\ge1$ (see comment below 1st paragraph).

$
\begin{align}
\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi^\lambda(y_1)p(r,y_1-y_2) dy_1\right)^2  & =\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi^\lambda(y_1)(4\pi r)^{-1/2}e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)} dy_1\right)^2 \\
& = \left((4\pi r)^{-1/2} \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi^\lambda(y_1)e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)} dy_1\right|\right)^2 \\ 
& \le \left((4\pi r)^{-1/2} \left[\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\phi^\lambda(y_1) \right|^2 dy_1\ \right]^{1/2}\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)}\right|^2dy_1 \right]^{1/2} \right)^2 \text{(Schwarz Inequality)} \\
& = \left((4\pi r)^{-1/2}\right)^2 \left(\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\phi^\lambda(y_1) \right|^2 dy_1\ \right]^{1/2}\right)^2\left(\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)}\right|^2dy_1 \right]^{1/2} \right)^2 \\
& = \left|(4\pi r)^{-1}\right|\left(\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\phi^\lambda(y_1) \right|^2 dy_1\ \right]^{1/2}\right)^2\left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)}\right|^2dy_1 \right| \\
& = \left|(4\pi r)^{-1}\right|\left(\left[\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|\phi^\lambda(y_1) \right|^2 dy_1\ \right]^{1/2}\right)^2 \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)}\right|^2dy_1 \right|\\
& = \left|(4\pi r)^{-1}\right|\left(\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left|\phi^\lambda(y_1) \right|^2 dy_1\ \right]^{1/2}\right)^2 \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)}\right|^2dy_1 \right|\\
& =  \left|(4\pi r)^{-1}\right|\left(\left[\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int_{-b}^b\left|\phi^\lambda(y_1) \right|^2 dy_1\ \right]^{1/2}\right)^2 \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)}\right|^2dy_1 \right|\\
& =  \left|(4\pi r)^{-1}\right|\left(\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\left[\int_{-b}^b\left|\phi^\lambda(y_1) \right|^2 dy_1\ \right]^{1/2}\right)^2 \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)}\right|^2dy_1 \right| \text{(square root limit rule)}\\
& =  \left|(4\pi r)^{-1}\right|\left(\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\left[\int_{-b}^b\left|\lambda^{-1}\phi(\lambda^{-1}y_1) \right|^2 dy_1\ \right]^{1/2}\right)^2 \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)}\right|^2dy_1 \right| \\
& =  \left|(4\pi r)^{-1}\right|\left(\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\left[\int_{-b}^b\left|\lambda^{-1}\right|^2\left|\phi(\lambda^{-1}y_1) \right|^2 dy_1\ \right]^{1/2}\right)^2 \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)}\right|^2dy_1 \right|\\
& =  \left|(4\pi r)^{-1}\right| ||\lambda^{-1}|| \left(\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\left[\int_{-b}^b\left|\phi(\lambda^{-1}y_1) \right|^2 dy_1\ \right]^{1/2}\right)^2 \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)}\right|^2dy_1 \right| \\
& =  \left|(4\pi r)^{-1}\right| |\lambda^{-1}|(||\phi||_\infty)^2 \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)}\right|^2dy_1 \right| \\
& \le   \left|(4\pi r)^{-1}\right|\lambda^{-1}(1)^2 \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)}\right|^2dy_1 \right|\\
& =   (4\pi r)^{-1}\lambda^{-1} \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)}\right|^2dy_1 \right| \text{(since $r>0$)}\\
& =   (4\pi r)^{-1}\lambda^{1-2} \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)}\right|^2dy_1 \right|\\
& \le   (4\pi r)^{-1}\lambda^{1-2\beta} \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)}\right|^2dy_1 \right|\\
\end{align}
$
(holds for all $\lambda\in ]0,1]$ and all $\beta \ge 1$; if $1/2<\beta<1$, then the inequality does not hold unless $\lambda=1$)

$
\begin{align}
\int_0^u\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi^\lambda(y_1)p(r,y_1-y_2) dy_1\right)^2 dy_2 \ dr  
& =\int_0^u\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left(\int_{\mathbb{R}}\phi^\lambda(y_1)(4\pi r)^{-1/2}e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)} dy_1\right)^2 dy_2 \ dr\\
&\le \int_0^u\int_{\mathbb{R}} (4\pi r)^{-1} \lambda^{1-2\beta} \left|\int_{\mathbb{R}}\left|e^{-(y_1-y_2)^2/(4r)}\right|^2dy_1 \right| dy_2 \ dr\\
&= \lambda^{1-2\beta} \int_0^u Cu^{\varepsilon-1} \ dr\\
&=Cu^{\varepsilon-1} \lambda^{1-2\beta} \int_0^u  \ dr\\
&=Cu^{\varepsilon-1} \lambda^{1-2\beta} u\\
&=Cu^{\varepsilon} \lambda^{1-2\beta}\\
\end{align}
$